# Python Script Fails To Run When Launched From Shell File, But Works When Launched From Terminal

Tags: python, macos, shell, terminal, google-code

If I launch the Google Code upload Python script from Terminal, it works as expected, but when I launch it using the code below in a Bourne Shell Script file, it fails with the error "`close failed in file object destructor: Error in sys.excepthook: Original exception was:`".

```
#!/bin/sh
BUILD_FOLDER="/Users/James/Documents/Xcode Projects/Uber Sweep - Mac/build/Release & Package"

if [ -f "$BUILD_FOLDER/Uber Sweep (64 bit).zip" ]; then
python /Users/James/Scripts/Google\ Code\ Upload.py -s "Uber Sweep - Mac OS X (64 bit)" -p "uber-sweep" -u "EXCLUDED" -l "Featured,Type-Archive,OpSys-OSX" "$BUILD_FOLDER/Uber Sweep (64 bit).zip" | echo
fi
```

Why is this?

Thank you for your help,
jrtc27

Comment: `echo` doesn't accept anything from stdin, so it's doing nothing but outputting a blank line. Try specifying the full path to `python`. The `PATH` for the script may be different than it is for your interactive shell. You should be able to quote the name of your Python script and avoid the awkward escaping of spaces.

Comment: was that the full exception message? if not then please post the full exception message. also please post the code or link to `Google\ Code\ Upload.py`. and why do you pipe the python script to `echo`?

Comment: That is the full error message I get, unfortunately. I pipe it to `echo` so that I can view the result of the script. `Google Code Upload.py` is an unmodified version of [Google's own script](http://code.google.com/p/support/source/browse/trunk/scripts/googlecode_upload.py) - note that I took r190 (latest version at time of posting).

Comment: I stopped piping it to echo it works now. Thank you for your help. @Dennis, if you post your comment as an answer (you commented first), I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` doesn't accept anything from stdin, so it's doing nothing but outputting a blank line. The script's output should appear without having to do anything to it.

Try specifying the full path to `python`. The `PATH` for the script may be different than it is for your interactive shell.

You should be able to quote the name of your Python script and avoid the awkward escaping of spaces.